# Creating an element in an element with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

I'm trying to create an element with an element inside of it in JQuery, but I'm not getting anything when I try and output it.

This is the HTML equivalent of what I'm looking for:

HTML:

```
<div class="btn-icn">
   <button class="btn">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span>
   </button>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
a = $(button).attr({
     class: "btn";
     id:"btn";
 }.append($(icon).attr({
     class:"glyphicon glyphicon-comment";
     id="comment";
 }));

alert(a);
```

Comment: what are inside `button` and `icon` variables?

Comment: That indentation though... Pretty sure there is a syntax error somewhere.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon not one but 5 syntax errors

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("<button/>", { // here goes the properties:
  appendTo : ".btn-icn",
  class : "btn",
  id : "btn",
  on : {
      click : function(){ alert(this.tagName); }
  },
  append : $("<span/>", {
    class : "glyphicon glyphicon-comment",
    id : "comment"
  })
});
```

```css
@import url("//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
<div class="btn-icn"></div>
```

(Be aware that using an ID multiple times on a single page is wrong. Stick with classes instead.)

Answer (score 0):

The jquery code is totally broken to me:

```
var a = $('<a />').attr({
  class: "btn", //comma not semicol
  id:"btn"
});

var icon = $('<i></i>').attr({
  class: "glyphicon glyphicon-comment",
  id: "comment" //no equal sign in an object, property: value
});

a.append(icon)
```